# Java 8u20 core dump (thread dump missing stack trace)

Tags: java-8, stack-trace, coredump, jvisualvm, jstack

I recently used **jvisualvm** and **jstack** to analyse a Java 8u20 tomcat core dump.  For most threads I am able to see a full stack trace e.g.

```
Thread 21234: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) ...
```

But for the current thread (the one that cause the core dump) there is no stack trace and all I see is:

```
Thread 28888: (state = IN_JAVA)
```

I found the following explanation of `IN_JAVA`:

- `NEW`: Just starting up, i.e., in process of being initialized.
- `IN_NATIVE`: Running in native code.
- `IN_NATIVE_TRANS`: Corresponding transition state.
- `IN_VM`: Running in VM.
- `IN_VM_TRANS`: Corresponding transition state.
- `IN_JAVA`: Running in Java or in stub code.
- `BLOCKED`: Blocked in vm.
- `BLOCKED_TRANS`: Corresponding transition state.

The `he_err` log shows the method from java that is calling into the VM native code but I am interested in the rest of the java side stack.

Any ideas as to why this is would be much appreciated!

Comment: A littel off topic I think See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to reproduce the problem, or even just take guesses based on the rest of the core dump.

Comment: Regarding being off topic:  It may not include source code but it is about software tools commonly used by programmers.  Regarding not enough information: What information would help?  I am asking a general question as to why a stack trace would not appear in the thread dump.

Comment: Thanks for the editing gontard.